# Json deserialize issue in .net,

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I have Json coming as array of string object which is incorrect response json. I need make proper object out of full response. I am getting extra parentheses and double quote [" in the beginning and end as well. I require to get the json under string.

```
JsonOutput = "[\n  \" [{\\\"return_type\\\":\\\"FIELD_LIST\\\",\\\"return_value\\\":[{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"INVOICE #\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"FPT2021-95\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"10\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"21\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"DATE\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"01/03/2022\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"25\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"34\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"DUE DATE\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"02/02/2022\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"39\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"48\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"TERMS\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"Net 30\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"52\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"59\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"BILL TO\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"Freepoint Commodities, LLC\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"65\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"84\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"ADDRESS\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"58 Commerce Road\\\\nStamford, CT 06902\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"88\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"101\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"SUBTOTAL\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"6,650.00\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"121\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"130\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"TAX\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"0.00\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"135\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"140\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"TOTAL\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"6,650.00\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"145\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"154\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"LINE ITEM\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"12/27/2021 Sales 12/27/21 - 01/02/22\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"110\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"120\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"DESCRIPTION\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"Daily Attendance at SXL Eagle\\\\nPoint, New Jersey\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"124\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"139\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"QTY\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"7\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"143\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"145\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"RATE\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"950.00\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"149\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"156\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"AMOUNT\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"6,650.00\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"160\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"169\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"LINE ITEM\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"12/31/2021 RTC-82 discharge at Eagle\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"174\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"186\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"DESCRIPTION\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"Point, New Jersey (9618269-12)\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"190\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"205\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"QTY\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"0.00\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"209\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"214\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"RATE\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"0.00\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"218\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"223\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"AMOUNT\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"0.00\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"227\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"232\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"LINE ITEM\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"12/31/2021 EOM Inventory at Eagle Point,\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"237\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"252\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"DESCRIPTION\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"New Jersey\\\\n(9618269-12)\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"256\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"269\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"QTY\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"0.00\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"273\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"278\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"RATE\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"0.00\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"282\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"287\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"AMOUNT\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"0.00\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"291\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"296\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"LINE ITEM\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"01/01/2022 DS-31 discharge at Eagle Point,\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"301\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"315\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"DESCRIPTION\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"New Jersey\\\\n(12368405-2)\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"319\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"332\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"QTY\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"0.00\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"336\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"341\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"RATE\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"0.00\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"345\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"350\\\"},{\\\"fieldname\\\":\\\"AMOUNT\\\",\\\"fieldvalue\\\":\\\"0.00\\\",\\\"startoffset\\\":\\\"354\\\",\\\"endoffset\\\":\\\"359\\\"}]}]\"\n]\n"

expectedJsonOutput = "[{\"return_type\":\"FIELD_LIST\",\"return_value\":[{\"fieldname\":\"INVOICE #\",\"fieldvalue\":\"FPT2021-95\",\"startoffset\":\"10\",\"endoffset\":\"21\"},{\"fieldname\":\"DATE\",\"fieldvalue\":\"01/03/2022\",\"startoffset\":\"25\",\"endoffset\":\"34\"},{\"fieldname\":\"DUE DATE\",\"fieldvalue\":\"02/02/2022\",\"startoffset\":\"39\",\"endoffset\":\"48\"},{\"fieldname\":\"TERMS\",\"fieldvalue\":\"Net 30\",\"startoffset\":\"52\",\"endoffset\":\"59\"},{\"fieldname\":\"BILL TO\",\"fieldvalue\":\"Freepoint Commodities, LLC\",\"startoffset\":\"65\",\"endoffset\":\"84\"},{\"fieldname\":\"ADDRESS\",\"fieldvalue\":\"58 Commerce Road\\nStamford, CT 06902\",\"startoffset\":\"88\",\"endoffset\":\"101\"},{\"fieldname\":\"SUBTOTAL\",\"fieldvalue\":\"6,650.00\",\"startoffset\":\"121\",\"endoffset\":\"130\"},{\"fieldname\":\"TAX\",\"fieldvalue\":\"0.00\",\"startoffset\":\"135\",\"endoffset\":\"140\"},{\"fieldname\":\"TOTAL\",\"fieldvalue\":\"6,650.00\",\"startoffset\":\"145\",\"endoffset\":\"154\"},{\"fieldname\":\"LINE ITEM\",\"fieldvalue\":\"12/27/2021 Sales 12/27/21 - 01/02/22\",\"startoffset\":\"110\",\"endoffset\":\"120\"},{\"fieldname\":\"DESCRIPTION\",\"fieldvalue\":\"Daily Attendance at SXL Eagle\\nPoint, New Jersey\",\"startoffset\":\"124\",\"endoffset\":\"139\"},{\"fieldname\":\"QTY\",\"fieldvalue\":\"7\",\"startoffset\":\"143\",\"endoffset\":\"145\"},{\"fieldname\":\"RATE\",\"fieldvalue\":\"950.00\",\"startoffset\":\"149\",\"endoffset\":\"156\"},{\"fieldname\":\"AMOUNT\",\"fieldvalue\":\"6,650.00\",\"startoffset\":\"160\",\"endoffset\":\"169\"},{\"fieldname\":\"LINE ITEM\",\"fieldvalue\":\"12/31/2021 RTC-82 discharge at Eagle\",\"startoffset\":\"174\",\"endoffset\":\"186\"},{\"fieldname\":\"DESCRIPTION\",\"fieldvalue\":\"Point, New Jersey (9618269-12)\",\"startoffset\":\"190\",\"endoffset\":\"205\"},{\"fieldname\":\"QTY\",\"fieldvalue\":\"0.00\",\"startoffset\":\"209\",\"endoffset\":\"214\"},{\"fieldname\":\"RATE\",\"fieldvalue\":\"0.00\",\"startoffset\":\"218\",\"endoffset\":\"223\"},{\"fieldname\":\"AMOUNT\",\"fieldvalue\":\"0.00\",\"startoffset\":\"227\",\"endoffset\":\"232\"},{\"fieldname\":\"LINE ITEM\",\"fieldvalue\":\"12/31/2021 EOM Inventory at Eagle Point,\",\"startoffset\":\"237\",\"endoffset\":\"252\"},{\"fieldname\":\"DESCRIPTION\",\"fieldvalue\":\"New Jersey\\n(9618269-12)\",\"startoffset\":\"256\",\"endoffset\":\"269\"},{\"fieldname\":\"QTY\",\"fieldvalue\":\"0.00\",\"startoffset\":\"273\",\"endoffset\":\"278\"},{\"fieldname\":\"RATE\",\"fieldvalue\":\"0.00\",\"startoffset\":\"282\",\"endoffset\":\"287\"},{\"fieldname\":\"AMOUNT\",\"fieldvalue\":\"0.00\",\"startoffset\":\"291\",\"endoffset\":\"296\"},{\"fieldname\":\"LINE ITEM\",\"fieldvalue\":\"01/01/2022 DS-31 discharge at Eagle Point,\",\"startoffset\":\"301\",\"endoffset\":\"315\"},{\"fieldname\":\"DESCRIPTION\",\"fieldvalue\":\"New Jersey\\n(12368405-2)\",\"startoffset\":\"319\",\"endoffset\":\"332\"},{\"fieldname\":\"QTY\",\"fieldvalue\":\"0.00\",\"startoffset\":\"336\",\"endoffset\":\"341\"},{\"fieldname\":\"RATE\",\"fieldvalue\":\"0.00\",\"startoffset\":\"345\",\"endoffset\":\"350\"},{\"fieldname\":\"AMOUNT\",\"fieldvalue\":\"0.00\",\"startoffset\":\"354\",\"endoffset\":\"359\"}]}]"
```

How will I manipulate JsonOutput to get expectedJsonOutput in C# .net

```
public class ReturnValue
{
    public string fieldname { get; set; }
    public string fieldvalue { get; set; }
    public string startoffset { get; set; }
    public string endoffset { get; set; }
}

public class ReturnObject
{
    public string return_type { get; set; }
    public List<ReturnValue> return_value { get; set; }
}

var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ReturnObject>>(responseJson)
```

Comment: Give us the code

Comment: added DeserializeObject code.

Comment: I have asked same question to gpt but I am always getting different answers and those answers are not working at all. do you know why is that ?

Comment: Please remember the use of ChatGPT on StackOverflow is not permitted.  This includes comments.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Comment: Happy ChatGPT could help

Comment: @Tarazed I didn't use chatgpt to comment, I shared a chatgpt link with a person that actually helped them. This is not against the rules. As far as I understand, the only thing against the rules is actually posting AI created content on the site. Although you can correct me if I am wrong, this doesn't actually matter anymore since OP found their answer

Comment: @ÖzgürGüzeldereli I am not a moderator, but based on the recent moderator strike caused by the ability to moderate AI content, I have a gut feeling the moderators would disagree with you.

Comment: @Tarazed I am not posting AI content, that's my argument at least. Flag the comment and we learn about it at least. I am curious too now

Comment: Oh well I don't want to get you sanctioned, I was just trying to give a friendly reminder, if you want to learn, you could ask in Meta.

Comment: @Tarazed I don't believe link to chatGPT chat is actually against AI policy... But it awfully close to LMGTFY links... which indeed can be marked as "rude" (as visible intention is the same - calling out OP as ... less than capable to do basic research).

Answer (score 0):

The nested array is serialized twice, so it shoudl be deserialized twice too

```
 List<ReturnObject> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ReturnObject>>(
                                                   (string)JArray.Parse(json)[0] );
```